# How to "connect" objects in 2 classes to make them update each other?

Tags: c#

I have complicated problem (maybe with simple answer).

I have class, that contains some lines, points and "Markers".

`Marker` is a class that contains `Ellipse` and its center coordinates (`Point`).

`Marker` class has drag-drop implementation, that moves ellipse and changes `Marker.coordinates` property. That works.

However I want to use drag-drop from my `Marker` class to move points in SomeShape object (`Marker` objects are parts of `SomeShape`).

I thought, that when I create `Marker` object and I pass 'SomeShape.lineEnds[0]' to `Marker` constructor - update on Marker class will update also my `SomeShape.lineEnds[0]`, but Its not working.

How can I solve this? By using some references somehow?

I hope I described my problem clearly enough.

Code:

```
class SomeShape
{
    // this object is set of lines and "Markers" (class below)

    private List<Marker> markers;
    private List<Point> lineEnds;
    private List<Line> lines;

    // my object can redraw itself on canvas
    public RedrawMe()
    {
        // it removes own lines from canvas and it puts new lines 
        // I call this function after I add points to lineEnds collection etc.
        // or when I change coordinates on one of lineEnds (list of points)

    }

    public void AddPoint(Point p)
    {
        this.lineEnds.Add(p); // adding point to line ends
        this.markers.Add(new Marker(p, this, c)); // adding same point to new marker

        RedrawMe();
    }

}
```

Problematic part:

```
class Marker
{
    public Canvas canvas;

    private Ellipse e;
    private Point coordinates; // ellipse center coordinates
    private Object parent; // I store SomeShape object here to call RedrawMe method on it


    public Marker(Point p, Object par, Canvas c)
    {
        this.coordinates = p;
        this.canvas = c;
        this.parent = par;

        e = MyClassFactory.EllipseForMarker();

        e.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(e_MouseDown);
        e.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler(e_MouseMove);
        e.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(e_MouseUp);

        c.Children.Add(e);

        e.Margin = new Thickness(p.X - (e.Width/2), p.Y -  (e.Height/2), 0, 0);
    }

    public void MoveIt(Point nc) // nc - new coordinates
    {
        this.e.Margin = new Thickness(nc.X - (e.Width / 2), nc.Y - (e.Height / 2), 0, 0);
        this.coordinates.X = nc.X;
        this.coordinates.Y = nc.Y;

        if (this.parent is SomeShape) ((SomeShape)parent).RedrawMe();
    }

    #region DragDrop  // just drag drop implementation, skip this


            private bool is_dragged = false;

        void e_MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e){
            e.Handled = true;
            is_dragged = false;
            this.e.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
        void e_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e) {
            if (is_dragged)
            {
                this.MoveIt(e.GetPosition(canvas));
            }
        }
        void e_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
            is_dragged = true;
            this.e.CaptureMouse();
        }

    #endregion // DragDrop
}
```

Comment: Seems like it should work. Does the code ever get to "((SomeShape)parent).RedrawMe();"? (You check by Debugging or logging.)

Comment: Yup. It hits breakpoint on `((SomeShape)parent).RedrawMe();` line (I separated that line from `If` statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point is a struct, not class and it will not work like this.

I assume, because structs are not "reference types".

I created own "MyPoint" class with X and Y properties and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As for your problem, you want to "notify" the parent, although there are many ways to solve this the classic C# manner is by creating an event and firing it when needed.

On the other hand, you have the parent from the constructor. I think you should consider receiving an interface like `IDrawable` that will contain any methods you want to call from the parent, and through that notify the parent object that it can be redrawn.

In the drag n drop I don't see any code notifying the parent, so can't comment. but why not just activate the same call to `((SomeShape)parent).RedrawMe()`?

Comment: Dragdrop calls `MoveIt` function, which calls `RedrawMe` on parent.

Comment: And my RedrawMe method works (I put breakpoint there). It seems that point on list is not the same point that is stored in Marker.

Comment: Maybe you should add some "re-calculate" function to find the edge points

Comment: My redraw function makes and draws lines from `lineEnds` list (list that is supposed to contain point that is updated in dragdrop). Thats weird. It looks like point is copied to list, not added.

Comment: yeah, I didn't understand the problem